# How to wait for a script to finish and click "OK" on popup in IE

Tags: vba, excel, internet-explorer

I have over 3k address for which I am trying to find lat and long from this site
http://www.latlong.net/ so far it's semi-automated like it works but incase if the address returns not found on that site I have to manually click on "OK" popup button for it to work right for the next address.

Also I am stepping through each line using F8 because after clicking the "FIND" button it takes about a second to get the lat long so I am not sure how can I pause the script until it returns the lat long.

```
Sub LATLONG()

Dim i As Long, fI As Long
Dim ie As New InternetExplorer
Dim strURL As String
Dim html As HTMLDocument
Dim goBtn
Dim btnInput

strURL = "http://www.latlong.net/"

With ie

            .Visible = True
           .navigate strURL

            While .readyState <> 4
                DoEvents
            Wend

For i = 2 To FD.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    If FD.Range("H" & i) = Empty Or FD.Range("I" & i) = Empty Then

        .document.getElementById("gadres").Value = FD.Range("F" & i) & ", " & FD.Range("D" & i)

        Set goBtn = ie.document.getElementsByClassName("button")

        goBtn(0).Click

        While .readyState <> 4        '<~ This doesn't works
            DoEvents
        Wend

       ' If .document.getElementById("lat").Value = "" Then SendKeys ("{ENTER}") ' Tried to do this but this doesn't works as well

        FD.Range("H" & i) = .document.getElementById("lat").Value
        FD.Range("I" & i) = .document.getElementById("lng").Value

        Debug.Print FD.Range("H" & i) & " = " & .document.getElementById("lat").Value & "," & FD.Range("I" & i) & "=" & .document.getElementById("lng").Value
        .document.getElementById("lng").Value = ""
        .document.getElementById("lat").Value = ""

        End If
Next i

End With
ie.Quit
Set ie = Nothing
MsgBox "Process Complete"

End Sub
```

Any other reliable and automated way to get the lat long?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily access APIs that provide you the coordinates. I played with the google API that works very well, however it limits your requests. I ended up with another API from [www.datasciencetoolkit.org](http://www.datasciencetoolkit.org/) but I am sure there are many others out there.

Drawback: You have to deal either with XML or with JSON objects. I would recommend use the JSON-Parser from Tim Hall found at [GitHub](https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON).

The following code gives you an idea about how to call the API from datasciencetoolkit. If you change to another API, you have to figure out how the JSON-structure is and adapt the code to read the coordinates.

```
Function GetGeoLocation(adress As String, ByRef latitude As String, ByRef longitude As String) As Integer

' Const MapUrl = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/"
Const MapUrl = "http://www.datasciencetoolkit.org/maps/api/geocode/"
Const protocol = "json"      ' "json" or "xml"

GetGeoLocation = -1

longitude = ""
latitude = ""

Dim XMLHttp As Object
Dim strURL As String, strMethod As String, strUser As String
Dim strPassword As String
Dim bolAsync As Boolean
Dim varMessage

' Create Microsoft XML HTTP Object
Set XMLHttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")

strMethod = "GET"
strURL = MapUrl & protocol & "?address=" & Trim(adress)

bolAsync = False
strUser = ""
strPassword = ""
varMessage = ""

' Do the request
Call XMLHttp.Open(strMethod, strURL, bolAsync, strUser, strPassword)
Call XMLHttp.send(varMessage)
If XMLHttp.status <> 200 Then Exit Function

' Check result
Dim o As Object
Set o = ParseJson(XMLHttp.responseText)

Dim status As String
status = o.Item("status")
If status <> "OK" Then
    Exit Function
End If

Dim results As Collection
Set results = o.Item("results")
Dim result As Dictionary
Set result = results(1)

longitude = result.Item("geometry").Item("location").Item("lng")
latitude = result.Item("geometry").Item("location").Item("lat")

GetGeoLocation = results.Count
End Function
```